# download file from website that take query string (ex. www.example.com/files?id=123)

Tags: java, android, file, download

I use **DownloadManager**  to download a pdf file

and it's downloading well **when** i download from url like this :   *http://www.example.com/file.pdf*

but it's not downloading **when** i download from one like this:
    *http://www.example.com/files?id=123*
 (download is failed)

```
String url = "url to download";
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "name-of-the-file.pdf");

// get download service and enqueue file
DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
 manager.enqueue(request);
```

**the question is** how to download from url like this *http://www.example.com/files?id=123*

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not aware that `http://www.example.com/files&id=123` is a valid URL. Please provide a working URL that has a `&` without a `?`.

Comment: What happens if you urlencode the ampersand? (%26) Edit: CommonsWare has a point also. Is it the name of the file, or is it a parameter only? If it's a parameter, then a questionmark is necessary also, otherwise it's not valid.

Comment: you are right , i have to write http:www.example.com/files?id=1

Comment: but i tryed a working url with query string    but the download was failed   in this method

Comment: Please explain **exactly** what you mean by "Not working".  Do you get an exception?  Wrong content?  Your computer bursts into flames?  Help us help you.

Comment: it's give me a message that the download was failed

Answer (score 1):

When you ask for http://www.example.com/files&id=123 you are calling the service "files" with the param id = 123 (probably pretending to recover the file with name "123"). Not the same as http://www.example.com/file.pdf where you have the exact url of the file.

Don't know if you can change the configuration of the DownloadManager to deal with this kind of urls.